# How do I configure quarkus to run tests in folders other than test and native-test?

Tags: gradle, quarkus

I want to port a project to Quarkus, but in my project I have 3 source sets: main, java and integrationTests.
(They were working on the old famework).
When I port it to Quarkus, I get a message complaining that my test is not under `test/` or `test-native/`.
Is there any way I can configure the project, so it also searched in the integrationTest folder?

I am using Quarkus, Java and Gradle.

This is the error I get. There is no stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The test class class YourTest is not located in any of the directories [classes/scala/native-test, classes/java/test, classes/scala/test, classes/java/native-test, /test-classes, bin/test, classes/kotlin/test, classes/kotlin/native-test]
```

In case it is important, this is how I add the integrationtest folder to my source set:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
            srcDir files("$projectDir/src/integrationtest/java")
        }
        resources.srcDir files("$projectDir/src/integrationtest/resources")
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the exact error you get (with stacktrace if possible)

Comment: What kind of problem are you facing?

Comment: Sorry @MaxRydahlAndersen for the delay. I updated the question with the error I am getting.

Comment: Also cc'ing @geoand

Comment: Hm... I don't think this will work. Can you open an issue so we can address it?

Comment: Sure, I will do it tomorrow, thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: @geoand opened an issue on github: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8950